# How to make the h2 element not exceed image width

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm trying to make my h2 element text to exceed the width of the sibling element (image).

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  height: 25%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="single-container">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="single-container">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="single-container">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

codepen link
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LBGGWB?editors=1100

Answer (score 0):

You need to add some css to the single-container class.

```
.single-container {
  width:270px
}
```

Change the width to whatever you want :)

Edit: Codepen link - https://codepen.io/canadianeagle/pen/YjwwYg

Answer (score 0):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

img {
  width: 213px;
  height: 25%;
}

.single-container {
  width: 33.33%;
}

.innerDiv {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <div class="single-container">
    <div class="innerDiv">
    <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
    <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
    </div>

  </div>
    <div class="single-container">
              <div class="innerDiv">
            <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
            <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image <width class=""></width></h2>
          </div>
      </div>
  
    <div class="single-container">
            <div class="innerDiv">
          <img src="https://imagesvc.timeincapp.com/v3/mm/image?url=https%3A%2F%2Ftimedotcom.files.wordpress.com%2F2014%2F11%2F84146440.jpg&w=800&q=85" alt="">
          <h2>I'm trying to not make this more than image width.</h2>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Check out my solution on codepen](https://codepen.io/vasudevapitta/pen/GBoZNq)